# How to get length of a dictionary iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to check how many neighbours are there in the graph in the networkx object.

```
neighbours = nxobject.neighbors('Something')
print(len(neighbours))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'dict_keyiterator' has no len()
```

It works with print(len(list(neighbours))) but a new problem arises:

```
print(len(list(neighbours))) 
for child in neighbours: 
  #Do some work 
    return Done_work 
return None
```

Now, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterator can be used only once. Convert it to a list, then measure the length of the list and/or use that list for further processing:

```
neighbours = list(nxobject.neighbors('Something'))
print(len(neighbours))
```

Comment: Need the iterator twice. Can I not make a copy? All I need is to check how many neigbours are there in the loop: If(neighbour <=1): Don't work else Do work

Comment: Once you convert the iterator to a list, you can use that list instead of the iterator.